# JIRA simple scripted validator - check if all checkboxes are checked

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to have a condition to check if all the options of the checkboxes are checked before transitioning to the closed/done state. Is there a way to do it easier or how to check if all the options are checked using the simple scripted validator?

Answer (score 0):

There is example if you mean ScriptRunner Simple Validator:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.manager.OptionsManager

cfId = 121500L  // paste you field id here
cfValue = getCustomFieldValue(issue, cfId)
cfOptions = getCfOptions(issue, cfId)
return cfValue?.size() == cfOptions?.size()

// return current cf value
def getCustomFieldValue(issue, Long cfId) {
    issue.getCustomFieldValue(ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(cfId))
}

// returns all options for select custom field
def getCfOptions(issue, Long cfId) {
    def cfObj = ComponentAccessor.customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject(cfId)
    def fieldConfig = cfObj.getRelevantConfig(issue)
    ComponentAccessor.getComponent(OptionsManager).getOptions(fieldConfig)
}
```